# Accessing shared object data without reloading swf – Is this possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, shared-objects

I'm wondering if it's possible to access a shared object's data (once it's been changed) without reloading the swf. Specifically, I have two swfs: one changes the data in the so and lets the second swf "know" via a localconnection. I have a function in the second swf that fires via the local connection. The function below:

```
function getNewValue():void{
    totalOrderSO = SharedObject.getLocal("orderTotal", "/");
    test_txt.text = (totalOrderSO.data.subtotalArray.length).toString();
}
```

This function looks for the new value however it doesn't show the updated value in my textfield unless I refresh the browser. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you call `sharedObject.flush()` after writing the data to it?

Answer (score 0):

after addign values to the SahredObject you should call the flush() methode to make sure that the data has been added